# Extract nested element value from JSON object using JMESPath

Tags: javascript, json, jmespath

I am trying to extract and transform elements from a JSON document using `JMESPath`.  Here is my test JSON array:

```
const search = jmespath.search;
const testData =
{
"ServiceAccount": [
    {
        "Type": "WIDGET",
        "ID": [
            {
                "OrderNum": "12345",
                "OrderTyp": "ABDCD"
            }
        ]
      }
    ]
};
```

I am trying to extract the value of the `OrderNum` key using the following JMESPath expression, but it returns `null`.  Here is my search expression:

```
const result = search(testData, 'ServiceAccount.ID.OrderNum');
console.log(result);
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const testData =
{
"ServiceAccount": [
    {
        "Type": "WIDGET",
        "ID": [
            {
                "OrderNum": "12345",
                "OrderTyp": "ABDCD"
            }
        ]
      }
    ]
};

const result = jmespath.search(testData, 'ServiceAccount[].ID[].OrderNum');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks @josip.  Yes, your suggestion worked.  I did not appreciate the significance of the square brackets.  My sample `testData` represents only a small portion of a much larger JSON object that contains lots of square brackets.

Comment: Hi @josip - Do you know if it is a problem to use square brackets with JMESPath?  Your solution involved removing the square brackets, but this renders my JSON object invalid.

Comment: @DanielAttard no it is not problem, i should not modify your example data, i took too little time to inspect the problem, my bad, i fixed my answer, now it works with your data structure. Regards.