# Sum values of JSON array using JMESPath

Tags: arrays, json, jmespath

I am trying to use the `sum` function of `JMESPath` but having some trouble.  I managed to figure out how to use the search function with multiple conditions.  This statement:

```
var x = search(myData, "Account[].Details[? Year=='2018' && Title=='ABC'].Amount");
```

returns this JSON array:

```
["2404.00", "2404.00", "2402.67", "2699.00", "2699.00", "2698.49"]
```

Now what I would like to do is to sum these values.  The [JMESPath specification](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#sum) says to use this syntax for the built-in `sum` function:

```
number sum(array[number] $collection)
```

I don't understand how to use this function.  Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'we took your [last example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51715463/extract-nested-element-value-from-json-object-using-jmespath/51715629#51715629) and added some more example data, we will sum Prices

```js
const testData =
{
"ServiceAccount": [
    {
        "Type": "WIDGET",
        "ID": [
            {
                "OrderNum": "12345",
                "OrderTyp": "ABDCD",
                "Price": "10",
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Type": "WIDGET",
        "ID": [
            {
                "OrderNum": "22345",
                "OrderTyp": "ZBDCD",
                "Price": "20",
            }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Type": "WIDGET",
        "ID": [
            {
                "OrderNum": "22385",
                "OrderTyp": "ZBDXD",
                "Price": "30",
            }
        ]
      }
    ]
};

const result = jmespath.search(testData, 'sum(ServiceAccount[].ID[].Price.to_number(@))');

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jmespath/0.15.0/jmespath.min.js"></script>
```

Answer to your current problem then would be this:

```
var x = search(myData, "sum(Account[].Details[? Year=='2018' && Title=='ABC'].Amount.to_number(@))");
```

Comment: Using the `testData` from this question, how would we sum the `Price` values, only where the `OrderNum` is > 20000?  I tried using `var x = search(myData, "sum(Account[].Details[? OrderNum> 20000].Price.to_number(@))");` but I get this error: `Uncaught Error: TypeError: sum() expected argument 1 to be type 8 but received type 3 instead.`

Comment: @DanielAttard like this: var x = search(myData, "sum(Account[].Details[? OrderNum> 20000].Price | [].to_number(@))")

Comment: @DanielAttard i frogot to explain the error, the error is caused because the result is nested list, so you need to use pipe and "Flat operator" to flatten the list and then sum it.